# Why can't parse all div elements in the target.html with lxml.html?

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing, lxml

Please download the file in dropbox and save it as `/tmp/target.html`.

[target.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pa0jnsnkhpt41b9/target.html?dl=0)

Open it in firefox with firebug to watch the html struture.

[image]

It is clear that there are at least 10 div in `target.html`.
Now to parse all div elements in the target.html with lxml.html.

```
python3
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc=lxml.html.parse("/tmp/target.html")
>>> divs=doc.xpath("//div")
>>> len(divs)
4
```

Get the result  `4`,why so many divs can't be parsed with above code?
At lease 10 divs in the `target.html`.
Same thing for parsing table in `target.html` too.
There are at least 9 tables in `target.html`,please check it with firebug.

```
python3
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc=lxml.html.parse("/tmp/target.html")
>>> tables=doc.xpath("//table")
>>> len(tables)
3
```

Comment: The HTML parsers in browsers follow the HTML parsing algorithm in the HTML spec. But the lxml HTML parser doesn’t. So the HTML structure shown in the question results from Firefox using the HTML parsing algorithm. But the result you get from using lxml.html.parse is a different structure — because instead of being based on the HTML spec’s standard HTML parsing algorithm that browsers use, it’s instead just based on some undocumented ad-hoc algorithm. And that algorithm in some cases produces a different structure than the standard HTML parsing algorithm. Apparently this is one of those cases.

Comment: In other words don't count the divs in the dom inspector, count the divs in the page source. Because some of those could have been added later.

Comment: @pguardiario There are ten divs in the page source. The difference between the source and what’s shown in the dom inspector isn’t the problem. The problem is that the lxml HTML parser parses the input differently than browser HTML parsers.

Comment: In python, to get the same HTML structure that browser parsers build, you can use html5lib. Try this: `python -c "import html5lib; doc = html5lib.parse(open('/tmp/target.html', 'rb'), treebuilder='lxml', namespaceHTMLElements=False); divs=doc.xpath('//div'); print(len(divs))"`. That’ll print 10 instead of printing 4 as the lxml HTML parser does. Try `python -c "import html5lib; doc = html5lib.parse(open('/tmp/target.html', 'rb'), treebuilder='lxml', namespaceHTMLElements=False); tables=doc.xpath('//table'); print(len(tables))"` and you’ll get 9 (instead of 3).

Answer (score 1):

Thank to sideshowbarker.

```
sudo pip3 install  html5lib
```

To install html5lib with pip at first.

```
import html5lib; 
doc = html5lib.parse(open('/tmp/target.html', 'rb'), treebuilder='lxml', namespaceHTMLElements=False); 
divs=doc.xpath('//div'); 
tables=doc.xpath('//table');
print(len(divs));
print(len(tables));
```