# Python's html.parser fails to retrieve parts of a web page (content of tabbed panels)

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve the content of: https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/ like this:

```
class LinkParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for (key, value) in attrs:
                if key == 'href':
                    newUrl = parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, value)
                    self.links = self.links + [newUrl]

    def getLinks(self, url):
        self.links = []
        self.baseUrl = url

        timeOut = False
        try:
            req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            response = urlopen(req,timeout=20)
        except:
            timeOut = True
            print(url,'timed out')

        if timeOut:
            return "timeOut",[]

        if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type') and not timeOut:
            htmlBytes = response.read()
            try:
                htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
            except:
                htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("ISO-8859-1")
            self.feed(htmlString)
            return htmlString, self.links
        else:
            return "",[]

parser = LinkParser()
data, links = parser.getLinks("https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/")
```

What I get differs from the actual content of the page (as seen with Chrome's view-source). I notice that what's missing comes from tabbed windows within the pages, could it be it? If so, how do I actually get all the content from the pages?

Comment: That code has an obvious syntax error (the URL isn't a quoted string).  Please post the actual code you're using, including the code that creates the `parser` object.

Comment: Oops, here it is

Comment: You still haven't shown us how `parser` is created.  Presumably it's an instance of `LinkParser`, but it would be nice to know that for sure.

Comment: Does that page have dynamic JavaScript which alters the page content after it's loaded?  If so, your parser would not see those changes, as it's not a full-fledged browser.

Comment: It may be because of the difference between the behavior of the ad-hoc default HTML parser vs the normal standard behavior used by the parsers that browsers use. See comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586527/why-cant-parse-all-div-elements-in-the-target-html-with-lxml-html#comment90139242_51586527 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586527/why-cant-parse-all-div-elements-in-the-target-html-with-lxml-html#comment90140447_51586527

Comment: @JohnGordon, I edited my question. What would be a solution regarding the changes that are not seen by the parser?

Comment: I don't know that dynamic JavaScript is the cause here; I'm just guessing.  If it is, then you'll have to use Selenium or something similar, which acts like a real browser and doesn't just grab static HTML.